# xmonad layout withIM stays the same size

Tags: haskell, window-managers, xmonad

I have a problem with xmonad and the XMonad.Layout.IM module.
I have the following configuration for my layout and no matter to what I change the parameter of "withIM", the window stays always the same size.

Config:

```
   38 import XMonad.Layout.IM
   39 import XMonad.Layout.Grid
   40 import XMonad.Layout.FixedColumn
   41 import XMonad.Layout.Reflect
   42 import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
   43 import Data.Ratio ((%))
```

...

```
   62 sPx = 1
   63
   64 verticalLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ reflectHoriz $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
   65 verticalLayoutLargeScreen = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ ThreeCol 1 0.03 0.5
   66 horizontalLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ Mirror $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
   67 webdevLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ Tall 1 0.03 0.63
   68 fullscreenLayout = noBorders $ fullscreenFull $ Full
   69
   70 myLayout =
   71     onWorkspace "2:web" (webdevLayout ||| fullscreenLayout) $ reflectHoriz $
   72                     (withIM (1%7) (ClassName "Chat")
   73                     (verticalLayoutLargeScreen ||| Grid ||| Full |||
   74                     verticalLayout ||| horizontalLayout ||| fullscreenLayout))
```

**Update:**
This is the output of xwininfo with the "(1%7)":

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1400006 "Profanity"

Absolute upper-left X:  3360
Absolute upper-left Y:  0
Relative upper-left X:  3360
Relative upper-left Y:  0
Width: 232
Height: 1042
Depth: 32
Visual: 0x7a
Visual Class: TrueColor
Border width: 4
Class: InputOutput
Colormap: 0x1400005 (not installed)
Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
Backing Store State: NotUseful
Save Under State: no
Map State: IsViewable
Override Redirect State: no
Corners:  +3360+0  -0+0  -0-30  +3360-30
-geometry 32x74-0+0
```

And the output stays the same, even after changing the parameter to something else.

Comment: “that window” – which window?

Comment: the window, of the chat.

Comment: Could you amend the question with the output that `xwininfo` shows after you run this command on the command line and then click on the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution is quite simple.
You need to restart your pc (or session) after you changed the rational parameter (e.g. 1%7, or 3%7, ...) and it works.